# Grunt Watch not working with file base set to subdirectory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm having an issue where Grunt Watch is not working with my subdirectory using Grunt. Here's my directory setup:

```
/home
  --/repos
      --/common
        --/node_modules
        -- gruntfile.js
        -- package.json
```

And I've set the base manually to the home directory in my gruntfile:

```
grunt.file.setBase('../../');
```

I'd like to keep my gruntfile located in this directory for working with other folks on my team and not use multiple gruntfiles.

Running 'grunt' works just fine. However, when I have Grunt Watch running, I get an error when I update my files:

```
Waiting...OK
>> File "repos/common/js/controllers/UserCtrl.js" changed.

grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
```

Here is the watch portion of my gruntfile:

```
watch: {

  // js
  js: {
    files: [
      'js/*.js',
      'js/controllers/*.js',
      'js/services/*.js',
      'js/lib/*.js',
      'm/js/*.js',
      'm/js/controllers/*.js',
      'm/js/services/*.js',
      'm/js/lib/*.js',
      'repos/common/js/controllers/*.js',
      'repos/common/js/services/*.js',
      'repos/common/js/lib/*.js',
    ],
    tasks: ['concat']
  },

  // css
  css: {
    files: [
      'repos/common/less/*.less',
      'm/less/*.less',
      'css/*.css',
      'repos/common/css/lib/*.css',
    ],
    tasks: ['newer:less', 'newer:cssmin', 'newer:concat_css']
  }
}
```

What on earth am I not getting here? Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### You missed installing the grunt module

The `grunt-cli` is a different module to the actual `grunt`. I think you should install `grunt` (that is what is meant with the local error message) at the local directory or above where your `gruntfile.js` is located.

Comment: Hmm. I did that but it's still looking for my gruntfile. I should clarify that I'm trying to keep the gruntfile located in the common repo directory. If I install grunt in the home directory, I would need to then keep my gruntfile there, no? Or is there a way I could point it to home/repos/common/gruntfile.js?

Comment: I am also new to grunt. I think it's best to have it installed in root of your app. Because many subtrees may use it later. You should install a minimum setup with a simple and direct running task to see if grunt invokes anyway.

Comment: Your grunt file can be anywhere in the subtree. you have to give the path to the cli. from /root you can "call grunt /sub/tree/mytasks.js"